# Is it possible to intercept third-party POST requests in a browser?

Tags: javascript

This is a technical question about browser javascript security.

We are running ads on our website. The third party ad script sends a POST request back to the ad network with various things in it.

We want to intercept this request and save the data.

Is this something possible to do in the browser on the client side, and if so, how?

Comment: It depends on how the ad script has been implemented.

Comment: Can you elaborate slightly? I can see the POST request in clear-text in my network tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to intercept HTTP requests by adding an interceptor to listen to *XMLHttpRequsets* in your website before they are sent out. To intercept the communication in XMLHttpRequest the main place to do that is the open function. In that function you can hook into the load event and then run your own functionality.

```
let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
    // do something with the method, url and etc.
    this.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // do something with the response text
        console.log('load: ' + this.responseText);
    });
    return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```